# How is zero 'overloaded' when assigning values to pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

This question was inspired by this snipped from a C book I've been working through

Where is says:

```
int num;
int *pi=0; // Zero referes to the null pointer, NULL
pi = &num;
*pi = 0;   // Zero refers to the integer zero
```

> We are accustomed to overloaded operators, such as the asterisk used
>   to declare a pointer, to dereference a pointer, or to multiply. The
>   zero is also overloaded. We may find this discomforting because we are
>   not used to overloading operands.

So I did a bunch of investigating with the debugger and my answer is what the debugger showed me. It's undefined behavior, I get that, but I'm not writing a program I'm trying to figure something out. Whatever the case, the pointer is initialized to 1 every time I run it, I'm not depending on that in some calculation, it's what the debugger repeatedly shows.

This is all just one question really, but I had to write more or it wouldn't accept it.
Why does *p=0 have different effects at different times? How is 0 overloaded?
How can I tell if *p=0 is making p a null pointer or if it is assigning 0 to a variable that p is pointing to? And how does the compiler know to assign a null at the address of p rather than the address that p points too?

```
$ cat prac.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num;
  int *p;                                

  printf("0) %p is %d\n",p,*p);

  *p=0;                                  //Why is this......

  printf("1) %p is %d\n",p,*p);

  num=5;
  p=&num;

  printf("2) Now %p is %d\n",p,*p);

  *p=0;                                  //....different than this

  printf("3) p is not null, %p : %d\n",p,*p);


  return 0;
}



$ ./prac
0) 0x7ffeb36b5c30 is 1    //pointer is initialized to 1, not-null, definitely out-of-bounds though
1) 0x7ffeb36b5c30 is 0
2) Now 0x7ffeb36b5b3c is 5
3) p is not null, 0x7ffeb36b5b3c : 0
```

Comment: Your code just causes undefined behaviour by using uninitialized variables,  the output is meaningless

Comment: Note that with `*p=0` you don't make the pointer point somewhere, you're not assigning to the pointer. You're assigning to what the pointer *is pointing to*.

Comment: if you have a variable `int *p; , then the statement `p = 0;` assigns 0 to `p` , that is, `p` is then a NULL pointer. The statement `*p = 0;` on the other hand assigns 0 to whatever `p` points to. You are not allowed to do that unless `p` points to something valid - which your code has many examples of not adhering to.

Comment: I think you are mistaking *pointer* and *index* notation. With an array, `array[n]` index notation is equivalent to `*(array + n)` in pointer notation (where `n` is simply the index (or offset) of the dereferenced element within the array) Obviously when `n = 0` pointer notation simplifies to `*array` to reference the 1st element of the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can you assign an integer value to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962226/why-can-you-assign-an-integer-value-to-an-uninitialized-pointer)

Comment: The pointer was actually "initialized" to 0x7ffeb36b5c30, not 1. And they aren't different. Why do you think they were different?

Comment: Good to see re-posted.

Comment: `int * p = 0;` is roughly the same as `int * p; p = 0;`. But definitely ***not*** the same as `int * p; *p = 0;`.  The `*` in the variable definition is a different from the de-referencing operator `*`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32136460/584518).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you're asking about is *null pointer constants*.

The C standard defines a null pointer constant as

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast
>    to type `void *`

So the expression `0`, which is of type `int`, is also a null pointer constant. (Note that a null pointer constant needn't be of pointer type.)

The standard further says that:

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the
>   resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare
>   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Given:

```
int n;
int *p;
```

this:

```
p = 0;
```

implicitly converts the `int` expression `0` to a null pointer of type `int*`, while this:

```
n = 0;
```

or

```
*p = 0;
```

does not perform an implicit conversion, because the object being initialized is already of type `int`.

The rules for when implicit conversions are invoked are stated in the description of the assignment operator.  The same rules apply to initialization, argument passing, and `return` statements. These rules explicitly state that a null pointer constant is converted to the target type.

See the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the C11 standard (large PDF).

- Null pointer constants and null pointers: 6.3.2.3
- Simple assignment: 6.15.6.1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the book or article you cite, but it failed spectacularly in helping you *Understand and Use Pointers in C*.

**What is a Pointer?**

A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` is stored in memory, e.g. `int *b = &a;`. It works the same way regardless what type of object the pointer points to. (a pointer, is just a pointer....)

**How to Declare, Assign an Address to & Reference the Value Pointed to**

Let's take your example and look at what each line does (ignoring your `p` & `pi` typos and using `p` only):

```
int num;    /* declares an integer 'num' whose value is uninitialized */

int *p = 0; /* declares a pointer 'p' and ininializes the address
             * to a the constant expression 0. (a Null Pointer Constant)
             */
```

See [C11 Standard - Null Pointer Constant (p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) which is a constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *` (e.g. `(void *)0`). Virtually all C compilers, and if fact the C-Standard provide `NULL` for this purpose. (see: [C11 Standard - 7.19 Common definitions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19) ) So you would generally see:

```
int *p = NULL;  /* declare and initialize 'p' to the Null Pointer Constant */
```

Next the unary operator `'&'` is used to obtain the **address of** an object. Here:

```
p = &num;   /* assigns the address of 'num' as the value of 'p', so 
             * 'p' holds the address of 'num' (e.g. 'p' points to the
             * memory location where 'num' is stored).
             */
```

The unary `'*'` opertor is the **dereference operator** and provides a way to directly access the value located at the memory address held (pointed to) by a pointer, so:

```
*p = 0;     /* sets the value at the address held by 'p' to zero */
```

Now lets look at your code and output:

```
int num;
int *p;                                

printf("0) %p is %d\n",p,*p);
```

**What is the address held by `p` and what is the value of `num`?**

You have attempted to access the value of an **uninitialized pointer** and an **uninitialized** integer. You have just invoked ***Undefined Behavior***. The defined operation of your code is over and anything can happen, from appearing to behave normally or SegFault'ing. You cannot access **uninitialized values**.

```
*p=0;

printf("1) %p is %d\n",p,*p);
```

`p` is now initialized to the *Null Pointer Constant*, you cannot dereference a NULL pointer -- Undefined behavior again.

```
num=5;
p=&num;

printf("2) Now %p is %d\n",p,*p);
```

Hallelujah! `num` is now initialized to `5` and `p` now holds (points to) a valid memory address! (but unfortunately once you invoke *Undefined Behavior*, the game is over, and you may or may not get the correct output, but luckily you appear to.

```
*p=0;

printf("3) p is not null, %p : %d\n",p,*p);
```

What does `p` point to? (hint: `num`). What does the *dereference operator do*? (hint: allows you to access the value at the memory location held by a pointer). So what did `*p = 0;` do? (hint: you just set the value of `num` to `0`, which is the value at the address held by `p`)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: In fairness to the book, I just started it, came across the interesting piece of code *p=0 having differing results at times and screwed myself up with the debugger instead of checking the docs...or continuing to read the book.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with chasing every rabbit-trail to its end. That's how we learn. We all screwed up pointers when starting to code in C. While pointers and pointer arithmetic are simple, it's a difficult concept to wrap your head around at first. Once you make peace with what a pointer is and that its `type` controls the number of bytes (offset) between `*p` and `*(p + 1)`, then you are on your way to a full understanding. Good luck with your coding.