# Empty body of Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, copy-constructor

I am not able to understand the reason. Despite having an empty body for the copy constructor, the code is working absolutely fine. And t2 is being initialized. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstring> 
using namespace std; 

class Test{
    int *ptr;
    public :
      Test(int x){
          ptr = new int(x);
          cout<<&ptr<<endl;
      }

      Test(const Test&t){
      }

      void set(int x){
          *ptr = x;
      }


      void print(){
          cout<<*ptr<<" ";
      }
};

int main(){
    Test t1(20);
    Test t2(t1);
    t2.set(20);
    t1.print();
    t2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behavior Because ptr is not initialized [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962226/why-can-you-assign-an-integer-value-to-an-uninitialized-pointer)

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot!