# Segmentation Fault in pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to compare both "arrays" and "pointers as arrays". When I run part1 and part2 separately, they execute fine but when I run the whole code, I get segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *p;
    int arr[5],i,var;

    //PART-1
    p=&var;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        *(p+i)=i+1;
    }

    printf("\n\nPointers: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",*(p+i));
    }

    //PART-2
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        arr[i]=i+1;
    }

    printf("Array: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int arr[5],i,var;

    p=&var;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        *(p+i)=i+1;
    }

    printf("\n\nPointers: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d ",*(p+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think error is in that p=&var;

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger and examined the value of the variables?  Are they what you would expect?

Comment: With your edit, you still have undefined behaviour as soon as you access `p+i` with `i!=0`

Answer (score 2):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour:

```
p=&var;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    *(p+i)=i+1;
```

Your pointer points to the address of a single integer variable. It is not allowed to access any memory beyond that.

Whatever happens to be located at `*(p+i)` is not allowed to be accessed. Additionally it is not initialized as a pointer and dereferencing it is another source of undefined behaviour. Both accesses can cause your segementation fault.

As with all UB, it may crash immediately or not. This is why runnign both parts crashes while they seemingly work separately.

Comment: Referring to your second point, even when I run the code separately, I am accessing  *(p+i).

Comment: Correct. As I said, undefined behvaviour can result in a crash or not. That's the nature of **undefined** behaviour. It is not defined to crash every time if you do invalid things.

Answer (score 0):

From your code

```
  int arr[5],i,var;
```

`var` is not an array so, this code access non initialized memory  it is undefined Behavior

```
p=&var;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    *(p+i)=i+1;
}

printf("\n\nPointers: ");
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%d ",*(p+i));
}
```

So change `var` definition to `var[5]`

Comment: @RaghavKakkar because it is undefined behavior

Comment: And see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962226/why-can-you-assign-an-integer-value-to-an-uninitialized-pointer